# Change the server of the character

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How can I change the server on which my character is?

Is there a way? I heard you can do it in WoW, but can you do it in SWTOR?

Comment: This was an option you were charged money for in WoW.  As for TOR, their site is down for maintenance until the midnight launch, so getting any official information is next to impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a server transfer, which does not appear to exist at this time. Typically MMOs don't release this "feature" at the start of a MMO when it opens.

Comment: I hope they do soon, my server does not have enough people.

Answer (score 6):

Character Transfer was made available on June 25, 2013 with [Patch 2.2.1](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/2.2.1/6252013).  To transfer your character to another server, simply go to https://account.swtor.com/user/account/transfer and follow the instructions.  The cost is 1800 Cartel Coins per transfer, or about $13.  This is what the initial page says:

> Your account...
>
> - ...must be in good standing; you cannot be in a suspended or banned status.
>
> The character you want to transfer...
>
> - ...must not have been transferred within the last 72 hours.
> - ...must be level 10 or higher.
> - ...must not be a guild leader. (Guild members will not have their guild membership transferred.)
> - ...should not have any items listed in the Galactic Trade Network. Active Galactic Trade Network listings will not be transferred.
> - ...should not have any items, credits or mail in their mailbox. In-game mail will not be transferred. (Items and credits in your inventory are unaffected).
> - ...will have its friends and ignore lists reset.
> - ...may need to be renamed if your name is already taken on the destination server (you will be prompted for a new name when you log in if this is the case).
> - ...will have its Legacy name set to your Legacy name on the destination server.
> - ...will have its Legacy level set to the highest Legacy level between the original and the destination server.
>
> The destination server...
>
> - ...must have been open for at least 90 days.
> - ...cannot transfer from a European origin server to North American destination server or vice versa.
>
> Additional server restrictions may apply. Character transfers may take some time to update on the website. Have questions? See the [Character Transfer FAQ](http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/5268) for more details.
>
> Unclaimed mail or auctions left on your original server are not eligible for restoration. For more information about transfer restrictions, please visit us [HERE](http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/4997)

Answer (score -1):

If I do believe the tweets from the SWTOR team, you can now change the server of a character.

Comment: This is not true.  There have been server merges but that's quite a different thing.